# How do you fix this error in IE: "The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address."

Tags: tls, certificates

I've searched for an answer for two days, I feel none even knows what the error really means. I have an Issuing Certificate Authority and it has one valid certificate, and I want users to access its website using an SSL connection. The website is configured to use https and the certificate used for SSL is the Issuing CA's certificate.

Here's the https binding:
[image]

If I want to open the http:// website to access certificate services it works fine:[image]

But if I want to open the https:// website this is what I get:
[image]

Comment: What domain was the cert issued for? This is not a security question but a server config question, but you do not appear to understand the problem, so I can't migrate it.

Comment: The answer is found in the answer to the question: how did you issue the cert for this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's be clear here:

> the certificate used for SSL is the Issuing CA's certificate

Do you mean you have an Issuing CA, and that CA has *signed* a CSR (certificate signing request) for the certificate of your domain (correct) or are you trying to use the *CA's certificate* for your site (wrong)?

In the comments of the previous answer, OP asks

> "How do I know the correct hostname"

to which the answer *should* be, that you, the site owner/designer created a cert for your site, with your domain name, generated a CSR, submitted that to your CA, then installed the CA-signed cert into your webserver.

The name listed in the CSR needs to match the name you are using for your web site.

The error you are getting is reasonable and correct when referring to your website as "localhost".

Examine the certificate your webserver is sending back when you get the error, and look for the domain name it was issued for.  Set up DNS or your local hosts file to point that name at your local IP address, and try again with your browser, but use the domain name instead of "localhost" and confirm the problem goes away.

Comment: "trying to use the CA's certificate for your site" Yes, why is that wrong? Also how do I check the certificate the website is sending back?

Comment: Never mind, I issued a new certificate with the "Web Server" template and this time I chose the Common Name and it worked :)

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked, and the advice helped.  In answer to "Why is the CA's cert wrong" - because your website isn't the CA.  ;-)  As you discovered, the web server template is the one you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing https://localhost/, while the certificate was probably issued for some public domain that you own. Standards compliant web browsers will check the certificate to make sure that one of the dNSNames from subjectAltName (or the Common Name for historic reasons) match the domain you are accessing per [rfc 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1).

Comment: So how do I know the correct hostname? I've already tried https:// IssuingCA.takfir.com and it still gives the same error: "The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.”